# how to add variable into the run configuration Eclipse

Tags: environment-variables, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse Keplero in C++. I've a project that depends on other shared libraries.

To debug the application I've to add manully all dependency libraries, but this is very boring. So I thought that I can update PATH enviorment variable from "Enviorment" in "Run Configuration". I added the followin variable:
`PATH:${PATH};${workspace_loc}\library\lib\x64;${BOOST_X64_NATIVE}`

`BOOST_X64_NATIVE` is an os enviorment variable (windows 7). But I've the following message: `Reference to undefined variable PATH`.

Well how can I set correctly enviorment variables on eclipse in a way I haven't to copy every time all dependencies.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just adjust the PATH enviorment variable:
On Run Settings -> Enviorment adjust the PATH variable. Note if you want to use an existing enviorment variable you have to use `${env_var:NAME}` where NAME is the name of the variable. So to add update the PATH befor the deployment of the program you have to add PATH variable `${env_var:LIBRARY_PATH};${env_var:BOOST_X64_NATIVE};${env_var:PATH}`