# Unable to determine _shell_command for underlying os: nt in Eclipse

Tags: shell, process, path, jython

I have a java application which executes a python script, which fails at the line

```
cmd = "cmd /c asm.bat < 1.ADD.asm 2> nul"
os.system(cmd)
```

This worked when I launched the java app from the Windows shell but fails if I run the app from within Eclipse debugger with

`RuntimeWarning: Unable to determine _shell_command for underlying os: nt.`

I also tried `cmd = "asm.bat < 1.ADD.asm 2> nul"` but got the same error.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
  File "MyScript.py", line 73, in runTestFile
    os.system("cmd.exe")
  File "C:\mycad\share\python\Lib\subprocess.py", line 456, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\mycad\share\python\Lib\subprocess.py", line 753, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\mycad\share\python\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1238, in _execute_child
    args = _shell_command + args
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'lis
```

The line 456 in subprocess.py is here

```
def call(*popenargs, **kwargs):
    """Run command with arguments.  Wait for command to complete, then
    return the returncode attribute.

    The arguments are the same as for the Popen constructor.  Example:

    retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])
    """
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait() # line 456
```

It is curios that I cannot find no os.system() in the os.py and my `os.system("cmd.exe")` calls `call` function in the `subprocess.py` instead. In `_execute_child`, at line 1238, `_shell_command` is None, causing error. Before getting there, `_setup_platform` is executed and it returns `_get_shell_commands = (['cmd.exe', '/c'], ['command.com', '/c'])` in both cases. The first executable cmd.exe is converted into `C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe` by `distutils.spawn.find_executable(executable)` whereas `cmd.exe` and `command.com` are converted to `None` when I start my app from the debugger. `distutils.spawn.find_executable(executable)` basically iterates all entries in `path` env variable, attaches executable `cmd.exe` to the end returns the result if such file exists. But path env is empty when app is Eclipse-started because I have overriden it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `mypath;${env_var:PATH}` in app launch configuration, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17673245/1083704.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, I encounter the similar problem. That's because the PATH environment var has been  modified, which lost

> '%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;'